# How can I stop loading my 'ProgressDialog' after a sign in test?

Tags: android

I created a sign in screen (in portuguese) and used a 'ProgressDialog' while loading, but it never ends. How can it stop?

```
    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignIn.this);
            mDialog.setMessage("Carregando...");
            mDialog.show();

            table_user.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
                    if (dataSnapshot.child(edtPhone.getText().toString()).exists()){
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                        User user = dataSnapshot.child(edtPhone.getText().toString()).getValue(User.class);
                        if (user.getPassword().equals(edtPassword.getText().toString())){
                            Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Login Feito com Sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Senha Incorreta!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Usuário Não Existe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

I waited for a long time, but it never ends.

Comment: do you mean `ProgressDialog` not dismiss when login is success?

Comment: did you debug and check if your method results in success.

Answer (score 1):

```
btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignIn.this);
            mDialog.setMessage("Carregando...");
            mDialog.show();

            table_user.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
                    if (dataSnapshot.child(edtPhone.getText().toString()).exists()){
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                        User user = dataSnapshot.child(edtPhone.getText().toString()).getValue(User.class);
                        if (user.getPassword().equals(edtPassword.getText().toString())){
                            Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Login Feito com Sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Senha Incorreta!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Usuário Não Existe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Put `mDialog.dismiss()` in OnCancelled block may be you are not getting success response.